# python regex with differing length "or" in look-behind

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I have many logs with commands in it. I filtered all logs with "useradd" in them, but now I want to dicard some false positives:

- ... /etc/default/useradd ...
- ... .../man8/useradd ...

The problem is that I want to see lines with false positive AND real command in them (see test cases).

I can only use (one or more) python regular expressions as I am using a log analyzer program - so no real python program.
These are the expressions I tried:

```
(!/etc/default/|/man8/)useradd # no match
(?<!/etc/default/|/man8/)useradd # look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
(?<!fault/|/man8/)useradd # works, but that's strange
```

In answers to other questions the regex was changed so that a lookahead could be used - but I don't see how this is possible here.

**[Edit: added some test cases]**

```
## no match
cat /etc/default/useradd 
less /usr/share/man/ja/man8/useradd.8.gz
## match:
useradd evil
/usr/sbin/useradd
cat /etc/default/useradd; useradd evil
cat /etc/default/useradd; /usr/sbin/useradd evil
cat /etc/default/useradd; cd /usr/lib/; ../sbin/useradd evil
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't clearly say what I wanted, should be more clear now

Comment: If using a third-party module is an option for you, consider [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) - it's much better than the stock re in many aspects. Particularly, it does support variable lookbehinds.

Comment: thanks for the info - in this particular case it is not possible but I'll keep that in mind anyway - who knows when I need it in python itself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion instead:

```
^(?!.*(?:/etc/default|/man8)/useradd(?!.*useradd)).*useradd
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Start of string
(?!             # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 .*             # any string, followed by...
 (?:            # this non-capturing group containing...
  /etc/default  # either "/etc/default"
 |              # or
  /man8         # "/man8"
 )              # End of group, followed by...
 /useradd       # "/useradd"
 (?!.*useradd)  # UNLESS another "useradd" follows further up ahead.
)               # End of lookahead
.*              # Match anything, then match
useradd         # "useradd"
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/aP5tO9).

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for creating a demo!

Comment: You, sir, should write a book on RegEx.

Comment: this is the perfect answer for the original question - but I rephrased the question and it doesn't match on the new test cases :(

Comment: @RonnyLindner: The new regex handles the test cases, but it will fail if the order of the items is switched (i. e. if the legal case isn't the last one on the line). If that can happen, it's going to be very difficult if not impossible to do with Python's regex...